# Getting 404 on Grails when not passing a model to render

Tags: grails

Upgrading from Grails 1.3.6 to 2.2.2

With the following in a controller, it gives a 404:

```
def help = {
    render(view:'/support/help')
}
```

If It is changed to this:

```
def help = {
    render(view:'/support/help', model : [:])
}
```

The page loads fine. Is there a reason for this in the new Grails? It says model is an optional attribute. Note that the first way worked in Grails 1.3.6.

Comment: Can you show the view `help`?

Comment: I could, but it doesn't matter what is there. Even if it is just the word "test", it does not work.

Comment: Works for me effortlessly in Grails 2.2.2, although it is [encouraged to use method instead of closures as actions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllers). Try to create a new controller - action and test the same.

Comment: @dmahapatro interestingly enough, with a new Controller, it works.

Comment: If your old controller is named `SupportController`, can you just try using `view: 'help'` inside render.

Comment: The old controller is named SiteController, so it's not that. I've also tried converting it to a method unsuccessfully. Also, copying the entire controller did not work. Really strange. I guess I will copy one by one until it breaks to find what was causing the error.

Comment: @dmahapatro The error was that an action called getModel existed. I suppose it was inserting that as the default model, breaking it. Interesting.

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced that's the issue. Something is wrong with that one, but it's not clear what. It seems the issue is on my side, though, so this wont likely apply to anybody else. Thanks for the help isolating it, though!